How to transfer string from one column to another if it doesn’t contains substring
In my Postgres table I’ve got two columns, one of them sometimes have strings, the other one is empty, but some strings from first column sometimes has substrings, I want to move data from first column to another if it doesn’t contain substring.
What I have:



col1
col2




some string
null


some string
null


some string with substring
null


some string
null


null
null


some string
null



What I want it to be:



col1
col2




null
some string


null
some string


some string with substring
null


null
some string


null
null


null
some string



I don’t want it to be selected, I want to update all table, because back then this column was used by TWO INPUTS on web-interface, and users puts there completely different information, but there is a pattern of substring that I found, that can help to separate data from one column to another. I’m completely new for PostgreSQL, so I need your advices.
I was trying to do it like this:
UPDATE table
SET col2 = col1, col1=NULL
WHERE LOWER(col1) NOT LIKE ‘%substring%’

But for some reason, it just moves all data from col1 to col2

"I want" is no question and this site is no code writing service. If you want to learn SQL, please visit a tutorial site. If you have a specific question about the code you wrote, please show that code and explain what is unclear to you.

@JonasMetzler I understand, I'm just trying to find help, not force someone to write code for me. If my post sounds rude, like I'm ordering something, I didn't mean it, it's because of my bad English.

The example you added works fine as long as you replace the left ‘ and right ’ single quotation marks with the straight, ambidextrous single quote ' - see PostgreSQL Lexical Structure and Quotation marks on Wiki. You need to show a way to reproduce your problem if you need others to look into it. My guess is your like doesn't hit anything because the real regex you used is malformed in some way.

An often overlooked capability of the update statement is to simply switch values between columns. So all you need is something like: (see demo)
update tab 
   set col2 = col1
     , col1 = null 
 where position('substring' in lower(col1)) = 0;

This works because SQL keeps a copy of the old row values throught the update. The position() function determines if the substring exists within original column. Its returns initial place where the substring starts.

Thank you so much! Zegarek’s edit is just exactly what i was needed!

You can use a CASE expression to update the table.
Only update when col1 is LIKE '%substring%'
Fiddle
UPDATE test
SET col2 = CASE 
              WHEN lower(col1) NOT LIKE '%substring%' THEN col1 
              ELSE col2 
           END,
    col1 = CASE 
              WHEN lower(col1) NOT LIKE '%substring%' THEN col2
              ELSE col1 
           END;

Output



col1
col2




null
some string


null
some string


some string with substring
null


null
some string


null
null


null
some string




If I set LOWER(col1) after WHEN, is it going to be alright? Sometimes this column contains numbers.

yes still works alright, I have edited the answer as well

Thank you very much for your answer and for your time!
